# Communication via bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to develop a application with Bluetooth communication between android and non android devices. Please suggest me something. How to transfer data . After transferring how will i know it is received. I am able to send a data but nothing is received in the non android device. Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have a look at the Android Developer. Here's a link to the topic on Bluetooth communication: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

I hope this helps.